# Edge Slide - line color change

Tags: color, theme

Is it possible to change the color of the "Edge Slide" operator line?
Thx

[image]

Comment: Hello :). I'm pretty sure that it is possible. Probably buried somewhere in Preferences > Themes > 3D View...

Comment: I searched there a lot and couldn't find the right option :( Maybe this color is hardcoded.

Comment: It seems to bee ... I wanted to direct you to Themes > User Interface > Axis & Gizmo ... that is what I would called and expect to be assigned to this ... but it is not. And you are right it is not in 3D View as well.